# App does not run after was Published "this app is not optimized for this device" but runs well with Emulator

Tags: java

The App was published ,i can install the app on my Mobile Phone but it does not open. "It says this app is not optimized for this device" but if i run it from Android Studio it runs normal. I uninstall the app and install from Google Play it does not run!pls help (thank you)

Comment: When you say "if i run it from Android Studio it runs normal", do you mean, you plug your phone into the computer and debug the app on the phone from there, or do you mean that it runs fine on the emulator?

Comment: yes i debug the app on the phone and it runs normal

Comment: Strange.  Do you have a copy of the APK that you uploaded to the app store?  If you uninstall the app from your phone, plug the phone into your computer, and from the command line run `adb install <APP FILE HERE>.apk`, can you run it from your phone then?  If you do not have a copy of the file, try menu "Build>Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)>Build APK(s)", then click "locate" in the bubble that pops up once the build finishes.

Comment: Thanks Erhannis ... it was an SDK problem...